# Weird issues while Running Tests in parallel in TestNG, works fine if run in sequence

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-extent-report

Using = Selenium Webdriver, TestNG 6.14, Java

I have three classes and a total of 16 `@Tests (Class A =1, Class B= 1, Class C=14)`

In TestNG xml, I have classes in different threads.

When I run the suite in sequence, everything works fine and results are appropriate
but when I run tests in parallel, I see that the extent report mess up report, shows different test names in different tests and different screenshots in different tests and also execution log from other tests. Everything seems very weird. I am not sure if its TestNG issue or Extent report issue, any guidance ?

Comment: Cant say more, until you share some code. From a quick understanding I would say while dealing with parallel execution along with ExtentReport, you should use ExtentManager. Hope you are doing it.

Comment: Issue is with the code and improper usage. Several similar parts have been created and you should find a solution with a quick search.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a simple fix, parallel execution looks like tricky, will need to go through various tutorials to make it happen, I hope the architecture doesn't change much

Comment: See the examples in docs, they will work without any changes..

Comment: Hi Karthik  - I am trying to understand docs, but confused in one thing it has shown two classes 
1. public class ExtentTestNGReportBuilder 
2. public class ExtentManager 
Do I need to create two base classes and extend these both to my Test class ? not sure how to use that in my code, please help

Comment: @Abhishek_Mishra - I am not using ExtentManager, trying to look for information on internet as how to use it

Comment: @viki https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/966
Check this link as it has a sample implementation of what i am talking about.

Comment: thanks abhishek, I still can't figure out the setup for parallel execution, there is no complete tutorial anywhere, I will keep trying to understand